# two boxes are same background color(left and right) but left_box lot of content and right_box small content?

Tags: html, css

i have used 2 box left_box(`float:left;`) and right_box(`float:left;`)
left box lot of content and images but right_box some content and images

It's working fine. i put fixed height two boxes are ending same but i put `height:auto` the boxes are mismatched.

when left or right boxes are increase that time other box background can increased?

i want to only using div tag.

Thanks

Comment: can we have some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your answer...

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

... it explains how to obtain equal heights. Specific to your 2 column question, check out the demo...

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-2-column.htm

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use `display: table-cell` on both of the divs (assuming they are one next to another).

Do know that IE6 won't like it.

Comment: No problem. Make sure you accept the answer as correct if you see it worked, it will benefit both the answerer and the community, as well as any future developer having the same problem as you. You accept by clicking the large hollow V mark to the left of the answer body.